# How to delete those characters which have appeared more than once in a string in java?

Tags: java, string

```
public class Main
{
  public static void main (String[]args)
  {
    String s = "Javaprogram";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder (s);
    String ans;
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < sb.length (); i++)
      {
    for (j = i + 1; j < sb.length (); j++)
      {
        if (sb.charAt (i) == sb.charAt (j))
          {
        sb.deleteCharAt (i);
        sb.deleteCharAt (j);
          }
      }
      }

    System.out.println (sb.toString ());
  }
}
```

So I have written a code to delete those characters which have appeared more than once. For eg: If input is "Javaprogram", then first we should detect which characters have appeared multiple times and delete them. In this case, 'a' and 'r' have appeared  twice so we should delete them. The output should be "Jvpogm". My logic seems to be correct.. but I don't why I am not able to get the answer.

Comment: You need to keep track of `i` and `j` better. For example, when `i = 1` you delete the `'a'`. But then next time `s[1] == 'v'` (because the `'a'` is now deleted) so calling `deleteCharAt()` removes the wrong character. Step through it with a debugger.

Comment: I think you need to iterate your string from the back to the front. That way the indices `i` and `j` still point to the correct characters when deleting them. The thing is, deleting a character moves everything after that index to the front.

Comment: Looks like you have a typo at `sb.charAt(i + 1)`. Should be `sb.charAt(j)`?

Comment: Lastly, you should decrement `j` after deleting for similar reasons.

Comment: Note that deleting chars in a StringBuilder you are looping on at the same time may mess up your lopping across the StringBuilder with the i and j variables. Mabe try to mark the chars that are duplicate first and do the deleting of those chars in a separate pass over the StringBuilder?

Comment: You could collect the chars in a set: `Set<Character> chars = s.codePoints().mapToObj(i -> Character.valueOf((char)i)).collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution using a Set data structure.  Essentially a Set cannot hold duplicate values.  By exploiting this property of a Set I can identify duplicate values in a String.  Then, I simply use the `replace` method to remove the duplicate characters.

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {

    String str = removeDuplicates("Javaprogram");
    
    System.out.println( str );
}

private static String removeDuplicates( String str ) {
    
    final Set<Character> temp = new HashSet<Character>();
    
    for( final char c : str.toLowerCase().toCharArray() ) {
        if( !temp.add(c) ) {
            str = str.replace( Character.toString(c), "" );
        }
    }
    
    return str;
}
```

Comment: Nice idea! But it'd be better to assemble the new String in a StringBuilder as String operations are rather expensive -> if(temp.add(c)) { sb.append(c); }

Comment: @JohannesKlug makes sense.  Thanks for the feedback! I will update my answer.  I'll have to think about it for a second, because I believe that would only remove the last occurrence of the duplicate

Comment: You're right... Then you might consider iterating through twice. Once to fill the set and another time to build the new string

Comment: @JohannesKlug what about inside the `if(temp.add(c))` conditional I check for the indexOf the character in the string builder and if that index returns non zero I append to sb?  Is that self defeating because indexOf is also a string operation?

Comment: That'd not prevent the insertion of the first occurence of a char with multiple occurrences.
I'm not sure if there is a clean way to utilize set even though I like the idea. So probably a HashMap is needed with ´Map<Character, Integer>´ to count it like Gavin posted earlier (and deleted it by now)

Comment: @JohannesKlug yea I think you're right.  Either we need to add a scalar to O(n) ( IE another iteration, and even then we may need some type of str op ) or use a hashmap.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, like Johnny Mopp pointed out:

> sb.charAt(i + 1). Should be sb.charAt(j)

however, this won't fix the application, as you're also concurrently modifying the Stringbuilder, so you'd also need to do "sb.deleteCharAt(j - 1);" as the index was moved by the statement before, and then you'd need to not increment j... But all of this is super inefficient and hacky. and can't remove uneven numbers of the same character -> if the first two "a"s are removed the program will leave the last "a" in there

A better approach would be to iterate the string once, and check if the character doesn't appear somewhere else. e.g. by using `input.indexOf(c) == input.lastIndexOf(c)`. If this is true, add it to the result.

Example:

```
String input = "Javaprogram";
String output = input.codePoints()
            .filter(c -> input.indexOf(c) == input.lastIndexOf(c))
            .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)
            .toString();
System.out.println(output);
```

Edit:
The approach of Gavin with filling a map is probably more efficient but has more code. As your program is probably only relevant for short strings (otherwise there will likely be no character left) efficiency is not really important here though.

Edit 2:
The most performance optimized approach I can come up with is this:

```
String input = "Javaprogram";
Set<Character> handledChars = new HashSet<>();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
char[] chars = input.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
    char c = chars[i];
    if (handledChars.add(c)) {
        int hits = 0;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < chars.length && hits == 0; j++) {
            if (chars[j] == c) {
                hits++;
            }
        }
        if (hits == 0) {
            sb.append(c);
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(sb);
```

Comment: Oops I deleted that comment as I felt this was neater and more efficient as you are "iterating" over the target string once.  I would never have thought to use `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf`, I learnt something new.

Comment: @Gavin It's still not ideal, as the combination of "indexOf" and "lastIndexOf" will cause the char array to always be iterated through entirely. But as long as readability is more important than performance I'd still prefer it

Comment: lets not forget that the JVM can perform a lot of optimisations, and things improve with each release.

Comment: Rather than replace my original comment, I have add an answer to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting characters while iterating the String causes the String length to change. All characters that come after the deleted index will move down one index. So to circumvent this, I'll iterate the String from the back:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "Javaprogram";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
    for(int i = sb.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        boolean duplicate = false;
        for(int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            if(sb.charAt(j) == sb.charAt(i)) {
                duplicate = true; // A duplicate character was found
                sb.deleteCharAt(j);
                i--; // Update i to keep up with the changed String length
            }
        }

        // If a duplicate was found, the original must be deleted as well
        if(duplicate) {
            sb.deleteCharAt(i);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

The String length is changing, that's why you still need to update `i`, whenever a duplicate character was deleted, otherwise the index will be out of range.

Running this will give you `Jvpogm` as desired.

Comment: Okay. got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer:

```
public class JavaProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "Javaprogram";
        String ans = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            String substring = s.substring(i, i + 1);
            if (!s.substring(0,i).concat(s.substring(i+1)).concat(ans).contains(substring)) {
                ans += substring;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(ans);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Jvpogm
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach is to create a new string out from the input considering the character frequency.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "Javaprogram";
    List<String> inputArr = Arrays.asList(input.split(""));
    
    List<String> outputArr = inputArr.stream().filter(i -> countCharacters(i, inputArr) == 1).collect(Collectors.toList());
    String output = String.join("", outputArr);

    System.out.println(output); //Jvpogm
}

public static int countCharacters(String chr, List<String> strArr) {
    return (int) strArr.stream().filter(i -> i.equals(chr)).count();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For regex fans:

```
String s = "Javaprogram";
int i;
while ((i = s.replaceFirst("([a-zA-Z]).*\\1","_").indexOf("_")) >= 0) s = s.replaceAll(s.substring(i,i+1),"");
System.out.println(s);
```

prints

```
Jvpogm
```

Of course, this solution requires a character which cannot exist in the original input String.  And change the matching character class as needed - currently alphabetics.

Comment: Cool solution!  One tip you can use `replace` instead or `replaceAll` since you're assigning a new value to s in every iteration.  I did the same thing initially in my answer

Answer (score 0):

As Johannes Klug referenced my suggestion in the text of his solution, and I had deleted the referenced comment I thought I better add it here.

The basic idea was to group each character with the frequency it occurs in the target string, once you have created the map you should remove all characters with a frequency less than your target frequency (in the OP's question two).
Once you have filtered out non-targets you can then iterate over the target string again filtering out any characters that are found in your frequency map.

Turns out you dont need to filter the frequency map, as shown below:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String target = "Javaprogram";
        int targetFrequency = 2;

        Map<Integer, Integer> frequencyMap = new HashMap<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < target.length(); i++) {
            frequencyMap.compute(target.codePointAt(i), (key, v) -> (v == null) ? 1 : (v + 1));
        }

        String result = target.codePoints()
                .filter(cp -> frequencyMap.get(cp) < targetFrequency)
                .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)
                .toString();

    }
```

(Oddly it turns out that Java 15 doesn't have an `Arrays.stream(char[])` method)

I am use `frequencyMap.compute` to replace the following `if/else` statement:

```
int key = target.codePointAt(i);
if (frequencyMap.containsKey(key)) {
    frequencyMap.put(key, frequencyMap.get(key) + 1);
} else {
    frequencyMap.put(key, 1);
}
```

As I said in my original comments the solution will largely depend on what it is you are attempting to achieve, the advantage of this method is you have a frequency map which you can use to perform other queries, about the frequency of letters in the target string.